# Unable to run unit tests with Snakeyaml in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, snakeyaml

I have created a Java component which reads a YAML file using SnakeYaml. The environment I use is IntelliJ with a Maven plug-in and my project is built using a Maven pom file. When I run the Maven test project, my unit tests all pass. However, when I run the unit tests within IntelliJ directly, they fail.

Specifically, the call new Yaml(myConstructor) below is throwing an exception:

```
Constructor myConstructor = new Constructor(....)
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(myConstructor)
```

The specific exception is:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.(Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/BaseConstructor;)V

Any ideas?

Comment: Take look at file -> proj structure -> artifacts. There can be error. Just click at "Fix" button. Also try recreate itellij project from maven configuration.

Comment: Thanks! Recreating the IntelliJ project fixed it. Do you know why that was required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take look at `file -> proj structure -> artifact`s. There can be error. Just click at "Fix" button. Also try recreate itellij project from maven configuration. Usually there is troubles with libraries scopes, like `TEST/PROVIDED`.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of the TestNG plugin. It's an issue for both IntelliJ and Eclipse.

Easily solved in two ways:

1. Update to the latest TestNG plugin version for your IDE of choice, hoping that the shipped version does not conflict with the one required for your project
2. Enable the "Use Project TestNG jar" in Eclipse (or the IntelliJ equivalent). This setting is available in the TestNG section of the project specific settings.

The second way would be preferred because TestNG dependencies will be managed by your build tool (are you using a build tool, right ?!) and you have a lot more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

The below worked for me

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```